# How does this prime number generation method work?

Tags: matlab

I want to figure out what the background of this code is, specifically, the reason of the commands written.  I understand everything until the first line of the for loop, but then I got lost with the second line:

```
N= input('Enter your number: ');

primes = 2:N;
p=2;

while (p <= N)
    for i = 2*p:p:N
        primes(i - 1) = 0;
    end;
    p = p + 1;
end

primes = primes(primes > 0)
```

Can someone help me to understand this code please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code implements the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) to find the [primes numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number).

It generated the array `primes` which contains the integer numbers from `2 to N`

```
primes = 2:N
```

The `while` loop iterates across the integer values

```
while (p <= N)
```

At each iteration of the `while` loop in the `for` loop, the multiples of the current value of `p` are generated within the definition of the set of values of the loop index variable `i`

```
2*p:p:N
```

at each iteration of the `for` loop the element of the `primes` array in the position `i` is set to `0`

At the end of the `for` loop, all the multiples of the current value of `p` are then set to `0`

```
primes(i - 1) = 0;
```

The process is then repeated for all the `integers` values between `2` and `N` by the `while` loop.

At the end of the `while` loop the array `primes` will contains the prime numbers between `2` and `N`.

```
primes = primes(primes > 0)
```

This instruction finds the numbers different from 0 in the array `primes` and re-defines the array itself by assigning to it all all the numbers different from 0 or, that is the same. it removes from the array `primes` all of the  `0`s.

By definition the multiple of a given number is not a prime number.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was halfway through my answer when this got posted.  Dumping my answer lol. +1.

Comment: me too haha that's funny

Comment: I've also edited your post.  Some of the formatting was very distracting and I've also included some links that the OP can refer to to better understand the problem. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer :), Can someone help me with this question please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32417757/how-can-this-command-than-uses-a-find-be-changed-to-an-if-and-for-loops? Thanks in advance :)