# How can this command than uses a "find" be changed to an "if" and "for" loops

Tags: matlab

To determine all integers between 1 and 50 for which n3 − n2 + 40 is greater than 1000 and n is not divisible by 3.  And then solve the question: 
Are any integers between 1 and 50 perfect (that is, are they equal to the sum of their factors)? The book gives the following code

```
n = 1:50;
       f = n.^3-n.^2+40;
       ii = find(f > 1000 & mod(n,3) ~= 0);
n(ii)
```

But I want to change this code only using a "for" and "if" loops. Can someone help me to change this code please?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I have edited my post :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
n = 1:50;
f = n.^3-n.^2+40;
results = [];
for num = n //let's get into n
    if f(num) > 1000 & mod(num,3) ~= 0
        results(end+1) = num; //store the result into an array
    end
end
```

It is very easy, but `find` looks like a better fit here.

Comment: Thanks a lot :), but why the "end" inside "results"?

Comment: @user the `end` you are talking about points to the last index of a given array and is used to make it grow. `results(end+1)` means `results(length(results)+1)`.